# using group by clause in a table with rank function implemented on it in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, rank

How can we use the GROUP BY clause in a table with rank function implemented on it in Postgresql?

```
 candidate_id |  name   |    status    | phone_num | process_fk
--------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------
            1 | james   | regular      | 0985905   |          1
            2 | kylie   | probationary | 098889487 |          2
            3 | Anne    | regular      | 095590    |          1
            4 | Olivia  | probationary | 09556451  |          3
            5 | Charles | regular      | 09445099  |          2
            6 | Hannah  | regular      | 0977988   |          2
```

Comment: What is your goal? Where is your current query? Any examples for input and required output?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.